# Tools namespace android listitem

Tags: android, listview, android-tools-namespace

I'm trying to use the "tools" namespace feature in Android Studio.
I'm trying to populate the `ListView` with dummy list items, for design purposes. The link [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) says the `tools:listitem="@android:layout/<filename>"` should do.

But for some reason, Android Studio keeps showing `Layout android:<filename> does not exist.` I'm trying to find a solution for it, so I don't have to run my app again and again with dummy values for testing.

I might be overlooking something very foolish, so forgive me. Here is what I have for now:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/controllerProfiles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/profiles_list_item"/>
```

And I have a file `profiles_list_item.xml` under `res/layout.` Any suggestions or alternatives?

Answer (score 9):

you should change the following line :

```
tools:listitem="@android:layout/profiles_list_item"
```

to this :

```
tools:listitem="@layout/profiles_list_item"
```

with `@android` you say that you want to use a layout from android resources but your layout is in your own project files.

Comment: I tried it. It still gives the same problem. This was among my first tried solutions.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am new to Android and am also stuck.

Answer (score 4):

tools:listitem doesn't work with ListViews in Android Studio 2.2. This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215172&can=1&q=-has%3Adevpreview%20attachments%3D0%20component%3DTools&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=7500). I've tested this in Android Studio 2.3 beta 1 and it is fixed here.

You can also move from ListView to RecyclerView as this bug doesn't occur at RecyclerViews.